# How many years the world's oil reserves will be enough?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

World oil reserves are estimated at around 240 billion tonnes. Its world production is 4.36 billion tons annually. Calculate how many years the world's oil reserves will be enough: a) if the current level of its production is maintained; b) taking into account the growth of extraction by 2% per year.
My try is:

a) $\frac{240}{4.36}≈55.05$ enough for 55 years.

b)  $4.36+4.36\cdot 1.02+4.36\cdot (1.02)^2+⋯+4.36*(1.02)^n=4.36\cdot \frac{1\cdot(1.02^n-1)}{1.02-1}=4.36\cdot \frac{1.02^n-1}{0.02}
=218\cdot(1.02^n-1)>240$

$$1.02^n-1 >\frac{240}{218}$$
$$1.02^n>2.101$$
$$n > \frac{\ln (⁡2.101)}{\ln(⁡1.02)} ≈ 37.5$$
enough for  37 years.

But the answer in test is a)55 and b)26. Can you help please.

Comment: If you didn't make an arithmetic error, it looks correct. On thing to watch out: you are dividing on almost zero: $\ln 1.02$, which can be the source of the error, if not enough precision has been kept.

Comment: A little trickery : n-1 is the number of years extracted, you would get 36.5, say 36 entire years, could the 26 quoted be a typo?

Comment: @PeterSzilas I hope that 26 is a mistake answer, but on my mind for 37 inequality $1.02^{37}<2.101$ that's why 37 reserve will be continuous.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used Excel to calculate this, and found that after 37 years, 235 B will be extracted, so it appears your calculation is correct. And doing a rough estimate, we can use an approximation 2%*26*e = 141%, so in 26 years, production should be about 41% higher than today. But 26 is about half of 55, which would mean that production would have to be, on average, about twice current levels. So even without a calculator, 26 is clearly wrong.

As far as speculating as to where 26 came from, if you divide the current reserves by the current rate plus the reserves times 2%, you get 240/(4.36+240*.02) = 26.2, which rounds to 26. So this could be a coincidence, or perhaps your teacher did something along those lines.